# Die Ersetzung des Tätigkeitswortes "anlegen" mit "installieren"

Tags: grammar, verb-usage

Ich bin über die beiden Verben "anlegen" und "installieren" verwirrt, da die zwei "to install" bedeuten. Ich bilde für jedes Tätigkeitswort einen Satz:

> Der Techniker hat die Heizungsanlage im Hause angelegt.
>
> Der Techniker hat die Heizungsanlage im Hause installiert.

Können sie wechselseitig verwendet werden?

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/installieren vs http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anlegen

Comment: Can you give an example in which “to install” can be translated as “anlegen”? I cannot think of one.

Comment: *A garden was installed at the location where the house had been demolished.* --> ein Garten wurde angelegt. Maybe far-fetched?

Comment: @SentryRaven-I just wanna say that the technician installed a heater unit in the house.

Comment: @SentryRaven, thanks, the dictionary examples of *install* that I had found were all of the kind where one would also prefer *installieren* in German.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case only "installiert" is correct.
As far as I know this is a case-by-case decision, so I cannot help you with a rule.

All I can say is that "installieren" is usually used for 'technical devices' I'd say, whereas "anlegen" also refers to plans or agricultural / geological things like "ein Feld anlegen".

Another use for "anlegen" is of course "an etwas dran legen" as in "den Zollstock(/ das Gewehr an die Schulter) anlegen".
An lastly "anlegen" can also mean "to pick a fight" => "sich mit dem Türsteher anlegen"

Comment: Also kann man 'Mein Freund hat eine Lagune im Garten anlegen lassen' sagen?

Comment: @DerPolyglott33: You could say that, but only if your friend has more money than God. This garden sounds rather huge, and the work required will cost a fair bit :)... but gramatically, it's fine. :)

Comment: Im Duden wird noch das Gewehr anlegen erwähnt ...

Comment: @Vogel612 hätte ich jetzt mit dem Zollstock zusammengeworfen, aber klar.

Comment: Akten und Computerdateien kann man auch anlegen.

Comment: @Ingo Computer-Programme widerum werden installiert.

Comment: @Mark Ja. Ich denke, "anlegen" (Garten, Akte, Datenbank, ...)  drückt aus, daß man nur den Rahmen oder Anfangszustand herstellt, der dann je nach Gegenstand sich entwickelt, gepflegt wird, usw.

Comment: @Ingo da ist die "Regel" die ich nicht kannte, top!

Comment: Der Neue in meiner Klasse hat sich heute mit mir angelegt. Vollkommen andere Bedeutung als etwa einen Garten anzulegen. Nicht verwechseln! Also auch folgendes geht: Nachdem mein Gärtner das neue Blumenbeet an der grottenfalschen Stelle angelegt hat, habe ich mich mit ihm angelegt.

Comment: "Installieren" würde ich eher für "einbauen" verwenden. Im Dt. für "Gas-Wasser-Installationen" verwendet. In Vor-PC-Zeiten hätte auch niemand gesagt, dass er die Stereoanlage installiert. Das ist aber inzwischen nicht außergewöhnlich. Sonst würde man sagen "aufbauen" oder "einrichten".

Comment: @DerPolyglott33: you probably mean lagoon, which would be translated as "Teich" here. "Lagune" is a "false friend".