# Anbringen vs. Installieren

Tags: grammar, verb-choice

> Wir werden den Schalter an der Wand im Wohnzimmer anbringen lassen.
>
> Ich habe den Schalter an der Wand im Wohnzimmer installieren lassen.

Hat das Tätigkeitswort `anbringen` dieselbe Bedeutung wie `installieren`? Können sie wechselseitig verwendet werden?

Comment: What has your research uncovered? Did the respective translations and definitions shed any light? What do you suspect the difference is? Do you notice anything in the dictionary's example sentences?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Die Ersetzung des Tätigkeitswortes "anlegen" mit "installieren"](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9936/die-ersetzung-des-tatigkeitswortes-anlegen-mit-installieren)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-Installieren- has a very broad sense, in which it can be used, nearly in every conext of that matter. -Anbringen- would be more related to physical matter, and so on ... You couldnt say "Ich habe die App anbringen lassen" (I have brought in the app), but you could say "Ich habe die App installiert" (I have installed the App). -Installieren- always works in any case where -Anbringen- would work, but not the other way around. It would be like the english -I Put in place- and -I installed-.

Comment: Given the [four possible different meanings of "anbringen" in the Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anbringen), IMHO it's wrong to assume that "installieren" works in every case where "anbringen" could be used.

Answer (score 1):

Nein, sie können nicht ohne weiteres wechselseitig verwendet oder ausgetauscht werden; "anbringen" kann auch andere Bedeutungen haben, die von "installieren" nicht abgedeckt werden. Es besteht zwar eine Schnittmenge (anbringen und installieren i.S. von festmachen, anmontieren), aber beide Verben haben auch Bedeutungen, die vom jeweils anderen Verb nicht abgedeckt werden.

Der Duden nennt [vier mögliche Bedeutungen von "anbringen"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anbringen), von denen nur eine synonym zu "installieren" ist (dort die Nr. 2, Beispiele siehe oben). Zumindest die Bedeutung von "anbringen" im Sinne von "einen Kommentar, eine Bemerkung anbringen" (Duden Nr. 3) ist im (gehobenen) Sprachgebrauch üblich; "installieren" wäre hier falsch.